# Scala Case accepting string parameter

Tags: scala, switch-statement

I need to add a new case to this actor that accepts a string parameter and prints it to the console.

```
def receive = {

    case m: Echo    => sender ! m
```

It is required to be called within the Echo case with ("m") as its argument.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: case s: String    => println( s ) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "echo case"? If you need some "m" flag to be the trigger then you will have to preprocess it before calling the actor

Comment: What's `Echo`? Is this a case class? Does it take a `String` parameter? Provide source (cut out the irrelevant parts)

Comment: @AlexSavitsky I believe the echo case is the case statement shown in the code.

Comment: No, what is the type `Echo` that you refer to, in the `m: Echo` snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a msg wrapper case class and use it as message to the actor.

```
case class Print(msg: String)
```

Then the code for printing looks like below

```
def receive = {
    case Print(msg) => println(msg)
    case m: Echo    =>
      self ! Print(m.toString)
      sender ! m
}
```